# Proof of a inequality concerning with smallest singular value and largest singular value of square matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation

The definition of largest singular value:

[image]

The definition of smallest singular value:

[image]

The Lemma:

[image]

I dont understand two steps of the semi-proof below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first point of confusion is an application of the [reverse triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality#Reverse_triangle_inequality), while the second is simply an application of $\min_x \{ f(x)+g(x) \} \geq \min_x f(x) + \min_x g(x)$.

Filling in some details:

\begin{align*}
\underline{\sigma}(A+\Delta) & =\min_{\left\Vert x\right\Vert =1}\left\Vert (A+\Delta)x\right\Vert \\
 & \geq\min_{\left\Vert x\right\Vert =1}\left|\left\Vert Ax\right\Vert -\left\Vert \Delta x\right\Vert \right|\\
 & \geq\min_{\left\Vert x\right\Vert =1}\left\{ \left\Vert Ax\right\Vert -\left\Vert \Delta x\right\Vert \right\} \\
 & \geq\min_{\left\Vert x\right\Vert =1}\left\Vert Ax\right\Vert +\min_{\left\Vert x\right\Vert =1}\left\{ -\left\Vert \Delta x\right\Vert \right\} \\
 & =\min_{\left\Vert x\right\Vert =1}\left\Vert Ax\right\Vert -\max_{\left\Vert x\right\Vert =1}\left\Vert \Delta x\right\Vert \\
 & =\underline{\sigma}(A)-\overline{\sigma}(\Delta).
\end{align*}